# Problem in Seq2Seq translation model when using fixed embeddings

Tags: pytorch

I have already trained a model using this code https://github.com/spro/practical-pytorch/blob/master/seq2seq-translation/seq2seq-translation.ipynb from PyTorch tutorials.

The next thing I am trying to do is train my model with fixed embedding.
I have an array of embeddings (length 16) for every word in the training set. For example:

```
looks   0.007668 -0.011884 -0.009672 0.011174 0.030010 0.023078 -0.028925 -0.003394 -0.028641 0.010982 -0.021261 0.009686 0.020191 -0.004228 -0.009142 -0.022826
like    0.007500 0.024508 -0.019484 -0.003581 0.007626 0.012839 0.003500 0.023110 0.008789 0.020518 -0.020819 -0.012393 0.011967 0.028991 0.010099 0.004167
that    0.004982 0.007892 0.020845 0.025090 -0.015644 -0.015740 -0.010126 -0.016822 0.007736 -0.023931 -0.014181 -0.031085 0.013599 0.027267 -0.013781 -0.028441
```

etc.

I used the `from_pretrained` method in order to provide my own embeddings. I changed the Encoder as:

```
class EncoderRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
        super(EncoderRNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        #self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, hidden_size)
        embedds = np.load('embedds.dat')
        embedds = torch.from_numpy(embedds)
        embedds = embedds.type(torch.FloatTensor)     #x = x.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(embedds)


        self.gru = nn.GRU(hidden_size, hidden_size)

    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        embedded = self.embedding(input).view(1, 1, -1)
        #print(embedded.size())
        #print(embedded)
        output = embedded
        output, hidden = self.gru(output, hidden)
        return output, hidden

    def initHidden(self):
        return torch.zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_size, device=device)
```

But when I train an error occurs:

> RuntimeError: index out of range at
>   c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch_1533090623466\work\aten\src\th\generic/THTensorMath.cpp:352

Can anyone provide any help on that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: File "train_pre_embeddings.py", line 309, in trainIters
    loss = train(input_tensor, target_tensor, encoder, decoder, encoder_optimizer, decoder_optimizer, criterion)
  File "train_pre_embeddings.py", line 226, in train
    encoder_output, encoder_hidden = encoder(input_tensor[ei], encoder_hidden)
    File "train_pre_embeddings.py", line 133, in forward
    embedded = self.embedding(input).view(1, 1, -1)

Comment: What does the training code look like?

Comment: Actually my best guess is that there is a word in your training corpus that doesn't have a corresponding word vector, and that's the index out of range it's complaining about

Comment: That's what I did. This code uses <EOS> and <SOS> tokens and i did not put the <SOS> token in the fixed embedding. But I dont have fixed embedding for <SOS>. I initialized it with 0.01s and now runs without a problem, but i dont know if my approach is correct. Is this right or should I do anything else? Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it. When you say "I initialized it with 0.01s" what does that mean? That you added it to the embeddings lookup map? What is 0.01s? If you're asking what values you should initialize it to - do the embeddings get optimized by training the LSTM? Or are they fixed? If they are fixed, maybe let <SOS> = <EOS> - "end" + "start" ? It's kinda hacky but hopefully better than random

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
When i say i initialized with 0.01, yes, i mean i added them in the lookup map. The embeddings where given to me fixed but there were not  lookup values for SOS. What do you mean by 'end' and 'start' in your equation?? That might be helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an implied "the embedding for the token" before each token in the equation. So if you have embeddings for the tokens "<EOS>", "end", and "start", I was suggesting a way to combine them that might be sensible